# Show duplicates in Mathematica

Tags: list, duplicates, wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica I have a list:

```
x = {1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6}
```

How will I make a list with the duplicates? Like:

```
{3,5}
```

I have been looking at [Lists as Sets](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ListsAsSets.html), if there is something like Except[] for lists, so I could do:

```
unique = Union[x]
duplicates = MyExcept[x,unique]
```

(Of course, if the x would have more than two duplicates - say, {1,**2,2,2**,3,4,4}, there the output would be {2,2,4}, but additional Union[] would solve this.)

But there wasn't anything like that (if I did understand all the functions there well).

So, how to do that?

Comment: The "except" you're looking for is Complement, as used in Brian Schroth's answer below. You can of course use it as `Union[Complement[x,Union[x]]` - this would be useful if you're using a version of Mathematica from before DeleteDuplicates was introduced (I don't think it's in v6).

Comment: Pretty sure that `Complement[x,Union[x]]` is always the empty set.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lots of ways to do list extraction like this; here's the first thing that came to my mind:

```
Part[Select[Tally@x, Part[#, 2] > 1 &], All, 1]
```

Or, more readably in pieces:

```
Tally@x
Select[%, Part[#, 2] > 1 &]
Part[%, All, 1]
```

which gives, respectively,

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 2}, {6, 1}}
{{3, 2}, {5, 2}}
{3, 5}
```

Perhaps you can think of a more efficient (in time or code space) way `:)`

By the way, if the list is unsorted then you need run `Sort` on it first before this will work.

Comment: Eh, I don't understand it perfectly, but it works, so thanks! I'll dig in it some more :)

Comment: Any reason you don't use the [[]] notation for Part? Ie, `Select[Tally[x], #[[2]]>1&][[All,1]]`

Comment: (Continued after a thought break.) So, actually, in the broken down example I'd usually be happy to write `%[[All,1]]`. I suppose it depends on the linear-ness of the nesting of the functions. Only a gut-feeling kind of thing, I'd say, and one which changes over time.

Comment: I'm with you, Will.  In fact, I often use `f@x` instead of `f[x]` to avoid Lisp-like nested brackets since I find them hard to read.  In other news, check out the solution I just added!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way to do it in a single pass through the list:

```
collectDups[l_] := Block[{i}, i[n_]:= (i[n] = n; Unevaluated@Sequence[]); i /@ l]
```

For example:

```
collectDups[{1, 1, 6, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2}] --> {1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2}
```

If you want the list of unique duplicates -- `{1, 4, 2}` -- then wrap the above in `DeleteDuplicates`, which is another single pass through the list (`Union` is less efficient as it also sorts the result).

```
collectDups[l_] := 
  DeleteDuplicates@Block[{i}, i[n_]:= (i[n] = n; Unevaluated@Sequence[]); i /@ l]
```

Will Robertson's solution is probably better just because it's more straightforward, but I think if you wanted to eek out more speed, this should win.  But if you cared about that, you wouldn't be programming in Mathematica! :)

Comment: That doesn't work. You need to change the defintion for `i` to `i[n_]:=(i[n]=Unevaluated@Sequence[];n)`. Also, quick testing shows that it's a good deal slower than Will Robertson's solution; it's hard to beat built-in functions like `Tally`, which are written in C or C++ and can take advantage of things like array packing.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work?  Pasting the function into Mathematica exactly as above yields the right output for that example.  Do you have an example where it doesn't?

Comment: The desired behavior is to return a list with a single copy of all duplicated elements, not every copy of all the duplicated elements. For the example you use, the returned value should be {1, 4, 2}.

Comment: Of course, my solution doesn't work right either. I really wish you could edit comments, but since you can't, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: I just did some testing as well.  I'm confident my solution works as written, but you're right that Will's solution is around twice as fast.  I stand by the claim that this one makes a single pass whereas Will's makes multiple passes.  But you're right, maybe array packing or whatnot makes up the difference.

Comment: Looking at it some more, I'm convinced that your solution works as written, too, because you mention using `DeleteDuplicates`; if you edit your answer at all, I can change my vote from a downvote to an upvote. It's a good solution.

Comment: Note the second-to-last paragraph in my answer.  The proposed tweak in your first comment changes "collectDups" to "deleteDups", which the builtin function DeleteDuplicates already does.  Theoretically speaking, this answer still makes fewer passes than Will's since DeleteDuplicates is just one additional pass.

Comment: Ah, thanks Pillsy.  Sorry, our comments kept crossing in the ether! :)

Comment: If the list was unsorted then my solution also needs `Sort`, which would close the performance difference (especially for large lists).

Answer (score 7):

Here are several faster variations of the Tally method.

`f4` uses "tricks" given by Carl Woll and Oliver Ruebenkoenig on MathGroup.

```
f2 = Tally@# /. {{_, 1} :> Sequence[], {a_, _} :> a} &;

f3 = Pick[#, Unitize[#2 - 1], 1] & @@ Transpose@Tally@# &;

f4 = # ~Extract~ SparseArray[Unitize[#2 - 1]]["NonzeroPositions"] & @@ Transpose@Tally@# &;
```

---

Speed comparison (`f1` included for reference)

```
a = RandomInteger[100000, 25000];

f1 = Part[Select[Tally@#, Part[#, 2] > 1 &], All, 1] &;

First@Timing@Do[#@a, {50}] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, Tally}

SameQ @@ (#@a &) /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4}

Out[]= {3.188, 1.296, 0.719, 0.375, 0.36}

Out[]= True
```

It is amazing to me that `f4` has almost no overhead relative to a pure `Tally`!

Comment: Great answer! I do enjoy dissecting your answers and I have f4 all figured out except for the `["NonzeroPositions"]` part.  I cannot seem to find it in the the online help.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @mmorris I'm glad you enjoy my answers.  You can't find it because it is undocumented.  Oliver Ruebenkoenig simply used it in a reply on MathGroup without much explanation, IIRC.  There are other SparseArray properties as well, each of which accesses a part of the internal format of SparseArray.  (Previously I was using another method to dig out these internals but this is much better.)  I gathered links to several uses of these properties in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7445/121) (each underlined word is a separate link).

Comment: @mmorris I had to figure out what each property does for myself.  Take a look at them first, and play around a bit, but if you need a description of what any one of them ("AdjacencyLists", "Background", "NonzeroPositions", "NonzeroValues", "PatternArray", "Properties") is, ask.

Comment: @mmorris here are a couple of answers where I used the `"AdjacencyLists"` property:  [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9797/121) [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10653/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this is a great answer! I was wondering though whether it would be possible to highlight the duplicates in the original list - that is change their formatting (e.g. color or font size).

Comment: Why I'm asking this question is that I have a list of names and am attempting to highlight possible duplicates. For example, `John A. Doe` and `John Doe` would be possible duplicates, and I'm trying to write code to highlight this.

Comment: @Vincent That's a different question.  You will need a function to find related (rather than duplicate) strings and also a way to highlight these rather than list them.  I suggest you ask a new question on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com. I know the soft-match string comparison was addressed for a different question but I cannot find it at the moment.

Comment: okay then, didn't want to post a dupe if it had already been solved. will add my question at mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Using a solution like dreeves, but only returning a single instance of each duplicated element, is a bit on the tricky side. One way of doing it is as follows:

```
collectDups1[l_] :=
  Module[{i, j},
    i[n_] := (i[n] := j[n]; Unevaluated@Sequence[]);
    j[n_] := (j[n] = Unevaluated@Sequence[]; n);
    i /@ l];
```

This doesn't precisely match the output produced by Will Robertson's (IMO superior) solution, because elements will appear in the returned list in the order that it can be determined that they're duplicates. I'm not sure if it really can be done in a single pass, all the ways I can think of involve, in effect, at least two passes, although one might only be over the duplicated elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of Robertson's answer that uses 100% "postfix notation" for function calls.

```
identifyDuplicates[list_List, test_:SameQ] :=
 list //
    Tally[#, test] & //
   Select[#, #[[2]] > 1 &] & //
  Map[#[[1]] &, #] &
```

Mathematica's `//` is similar to the dot for method calls in other languages. For instance, if this were written in C# / LINQ style, it would resemble

```
list.Tally(test).Where(x => x[2] > 1).Select(x => x[1])
```

Note that C#'s `Where` is like MMA's `Select`, and C#'s `Select` is like MMA's `Map`.

EDIT: added optional test function argument, defaulting to `SameQ`.

EDIT: here is a version that addresses my comment below & reports all the equivalents in a group given a projector function that produces a value such that elements of the list are considered equivalent if the value is equal.  This essentially finds equivalence classes longer than a given size:

```
reportDuplicateClusters[list_List, projector_: (# &), 
  minimumClusterSize_: 2] :=
 GatherBy[list, projector] //
  Select[#, Length@# >= minimumClusterSize &] &
```

Here is a sample that checks pairs of integers on their first elements, considering two pairs equivalent if their first elements are equal

```
reportDuplicateClusters[RandomInteger[10, {10, 2}], #[[1]] &]
```

Comment: Just realized that, with the optional testing function, this might not do everything you would want.  Suppose you are trying to find records in a database that are duplicated in some non-key attributes, so you write a test function that considers two records the same if they don't differ in the attributes you care about.  Tally will record ONLY ONE of the matching records.  What you really want in that application is something like LINQ's or SQL's GroupBy, GatherBy in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

This thread seems old, but I've had to solve this myself.

This is kind of crude, but does this do it?

```
Union[Select[Table[If[tt[[n]] == tt[[n + 1]], tt[[n]], ""], {n, Length[tt] - 1}], IntegerQ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another short possibility is

```
Last /@ Select[Gather[x], Length[#] > 1 &]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a list A,
get the non-duplicate values in B
B = DeleteDuplicates[A]
get the duplicate values in C
C = Complement[A,B]
get the non-duplicate values from the duplicate list in D
D = DeleteDuplicates[C]

So for your example:
A = 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4
B = 1, 2, 3, 4
C = 2, 2, 4
D = 2, 4

so your answer would be DeleteDuplicates[Complement[x,DeleteDuplicates[x]]] where x is your list. I don't know mathematica, so the syntax may or may not be perfect here. Just going by the docs on the page you linked to.

Comment: Complement[A,B] returns {}, not {2,2,4}. The problem is that it takes away all of the 2's and 4's, not just one of them.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case :(